# PayPal adaptive payments response

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the paypal adaptive SDK on github, for a simple 1 recipient payment, so I'm using the simple pay file.

https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php

I'm able to make a payment, I've entered all the details correctly and that's fine, but I'm just wondering where I get the response so I Know the payment was successful and I can process the order? Currently it just goes to the return URL, but where does the payment success date come from?

And also, if you could tell me how to send data like the order and user ID across that would be great too!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not check if payment was successful via success form, it doesnt recieve any payment information.
Instead you should use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) It will contact your server in a secure way and inform you on payment event. You can periodically pull your server on IPN message recieved for client via AJAX, to show inform what payment was processed.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, should have thought of this! Why would you periodically pull the server for an IPN message?

Comment: Also, I'll add the IPN url to the API all, but how will my IPN know that it comes from my script. In fact, if I'm only using one recipient, do I need to use PayPal adaptive?

Comment: If you want inform user on real payment process completion (it could take time in some cases), you can periodically ask your server if it recieved IPN message.

Comment: But doesn't a PayPal IPN already do this, it contacts the notify URL and if successful it can process some code?

Comment: You can use easier solution like a Buy now button + IPN notification

Comment: Thanks, one quick question, any idea how to send the item name with the angell eye script?